# Select / unselect all CheckBoxes in a range EXCEL VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I am creating a VBA macro to select all checkboxes in a sheet and it works fine but now i want to adjust my code to select and unselect just the checkboxes in a particular range.

Here is my code.

```
Sub Select_all()

Dim Cbox As CheckBox
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B7, B104")

For Each Cbox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes

If Not Intersect(Cbox.TopLeftCell, Rng) Is Nothing Then
  If Cbox.name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 104").name Then
    Cbox.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 104").Value
  End If
End If

Next Cbox

End Sub
```

I added

> If Not Intersect(Cbox.TopLeftCell, Rng) Is Nothing

but it doesn't change anything, and when i remove this part then it selects all the checkboxes in the sheet and i need only for the Range("B7:B104")

Any suggestions please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why did you define the range as `Range("B7, B104")`? That means it is only two cells, B7 and B104, not the range of cells B7:B104.  And then just under your code you put the correct definition of `Range("B7:B104")`, so just change to that.

Comment: Are they ActiveX checkboxes or Form control checkboxes?

Comment: @tigeravatar i did the same as you, i just pasted the code by mistake.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie form control checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  But I changed the cb# to "1" because I don't have 104 of them on my test sheet.  Any cb's in range B7:B104 will be changed to the value of cb1, which you can change to cb104 in your script.

```
Sub Link_Checkboxes_To_Cells()

    Dim cBox As CheckBox

        For Each cBox In Sheet1.CheckBoxes
            If Not Intersect(cBox.TopLeftCell, Range("B7:B104")) Is Nothing Then
                If cBox.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then
                    cBox.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value
                End If
            End If
        Next cBox

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  but strange why it's not working. i tried a new workbook and it's the same. do i need to add some reference ? or some configurations ?

Answer (score 1):

@JuniorDev

There are a few reasons why the above code doesn't work for you.  I'll try to list them.

The above code works for "Form Control" checkboxes -  Not ActiveX type checkboxes.  You would need a different code for ActiveX checkboxes.  Or you may not have a form checkbox named "Check Box 1".  But I think that would give you an error.  Or your other checkboxes may not be in the Range("B7:B104").  You can try changing that to Range("A1:Z10000") to insure your checkboxes are in the range.

If you are not sure what type checkboxes you have then you can run the following code to find their names and what type of control they are, either form or activex.  It will print the info in your immediate window of the VB editor.

```
Sub CheckboxLoop()
'PARTIAL SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
Dim cb As Shape

'Loop through Form Checkboxes
  For Each cb In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If cb.Type = msoFormControl Then
      If cb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
            Debug.Print "Form Control: " & cb.Name
      End If
    End If
  Next cb

'Loop through ActiveX Checkboxes
Dim ChkBx As OLEObject
For Each ChkBx In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
  If TypeName(ChkBx.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        Debug.Print "ActiveX Control: " & ChkBx.Name
  End If
Next ChkBx
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old post, but I hate it when a solution has not been provided and I know the answer, which is seldom. Thank you, this helped me on a project I am currently working on.

If you're like me, I change all my Sheet Names for sake of clarity.

```
For Each cBox In Sheet1.CheckBoxes
```

This line in John Muggins code limits you to the Sheet Name, "Sheet1".
I was able to change the line to...

```
For Each cBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
```

...and it worked perfectly.